# opencv fails to build with ipp support enabled

Tags: opencv

I am having some problems getting opencv to build with ipp support. I am using cmake-gui on debian squeeze 32bit and the most recent intel release of ipp (the complete `composer` package).

I think I have cmake configured correctly. When I build with ipp enabled, the build fails with this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/intel/ipp/lib/ia32/libippcv_l.a(ippcv00242as.o): relocation R_386_GOTOFF against undefined symbol `ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

This does not seem like a configuration type error to me  :-)

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Thanks,

-Andres

Comment: Get help on the OpenCV mailing list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I resolved this issue and thought I should answer my own question just in case someone else trips across this.

Apparently, the opencv lib will not build properly when you specify a shared lib build. When using cmake-gui, you must NOT set this option:

```
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS
```

By disabling this option, the opencv lib built and installed just fine

Comment: By disabling this option, i was able to build and install Opencv. But when i compile my application with opencv and ipp, it gives me hundreds of 'undefined reference to' errors while linking. Can you give me some hint?

Comment: @arshan did you ever figure this error out? I'm stuck here as well

Comment: @wprins unfortunately I was not able to solve the issue. I just disabled IPP support as far as I remember.

Comment: I wish I could be of help, wprins and arshan, but to be honest this was so long ago that I do not recall enough of the details. I was new to using cmake then so the whole environment was new to me. I am not currently actively involved with OpenCV. I would suggest the OpenCV related forums.  Sorry I cannot be more helpful. Good luck--I feel your pain and struggle.

Comment: I used BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF and WITH_IPP=OFF for things to work

Answer (score 2):

If your processor is not Intel family, do `cmake -D WITH_IPP=OFF`, you don't need it. Then `make`.

Answer (score 0):

I see the question is very old, but I have just stumbled upon this problem while compiling opencv-4.7.0. Recompiling ffmpeg-n5.0 with `--enable-shared` config flag solved the issue with opencv `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`.