# Error installing opencv-3.0.0-beta on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: opencv

I am new to opencv and i am trying to install opencv-3.0.0-beta on ubuntu 14.04. When running make command, I get an error at 54%.I followed the same steps mentioned in http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html. but I still get an error.

Below is the error message I'm getting.

> /usr/bin/ld:
>   ../../../3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx/lib/ia32/libippicv.a(jmp_ippiResizeGetBufferSize_16s_as.s.o):
>   relocation R_386_GOTOFF against undefined symbol
>   `ippicvJumpIndexForMergedLibs' can not be used when making a shared
>   object /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make[2]: * [lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0]
>   Error 1 make[1](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html): [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/all]
>   Error 2 make: ** [all] Error 2

Please help in solving it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your IPP configuration bugs. If you don't need IPP, you might want to rerun the cmake command with this option WITH_IPP=OFF.

Further reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508926/opencv-fails-to-build-with-ipp-support-enabled) about deactivate IPP and [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp-70-library-getting-started) to properly configure IPP.